# Number format exception on input of 0x20A0600000000000L into Long.decode

Tags: java

I'm trying to take an input of a hexidecimal Long into a program and values which seem like they should work: `0x20A0600000000000L` cause a java.lang.NumberFormatException, it says that the input string is `20A0600000000000L`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20A0600000000000L"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.decode(Unknown Source)
```

This is how I'm calling it: `long temp = Long.decode(args[0]);`

This also occurs using a different online compiler: https://www.compilejava.net with the previously stated value input as a constant, i.e. `Long.decode("0x20A0600000000000L")`.

As a few asides, this is part of a course and the value is the input that they gave, hence its appearance.

Comment: L is not hexadecimal digit

Comment: Yes I know this is the input that was given as part of the course.

Comment: Did you do any research prior to asking the question? The doc of `Long.decode()` is quite clear about the syntax it accepts, and there is to trailing `L` in there. I suggest next time you check, and you won’ t have to wait for someone else to answer the question for you. Said in all friendlyness. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suffix `L` in Java lets you distinguish numeric literals of type `long` from numeric literals of type `int`. Since `decode` is a method of `Long`, it knows that it is parsing a `long` number, so it does not accept trailing `L` suffix. Removing it fixes the problem:

```
long lv = Long.decode("0x20A0600000000000");
System.out.println(lv);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/nSjeK2)

Comment: if you increment radix to the proper value when parsing ofc . it doesnt accept L for hexadecimal parsing

Comment: @Bolzano Unlike `parse` which needs `radix` passed explicitly, `decode` figures out radix from `0x` or another prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the trailing `L`, try to remove it as next:

```
Long.decode("0x20A0600000000000")
```

Indeed `L` is not supported by [`Long.decode(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#decode-java.lang.String-) and even if it was, it would be redondant as it will convert the result as a `Long` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String tt = args[0];
    if( tt.endsWith("L") || tt.endsWith("l") )
    {
        tt = tt.substring( 0, tt.length() - 2);
    }
    long temp = Long.decode(tt);
```

If you already know that you will only be having "L", then you can remove the "l" checking part.